# Calling winapi export function from javascript?

Tags: winapi

I want to call DLL export function defined in C++ win32 DLL from javascript/HTML control at client side in browser.

Thanks,
Naeem

Comment: Which function do you want to call?

Answer (score 0):

You can't due to security and compatibility reasons.

What you can do is to wrap the DLL into an ActiveX control, mark it safe for scripting and then call it.  Of course ActiveX isn't compatible with all browsers or operating systems but that might not be an issue in your setup.

Comment: If you found an answer then let us know by posting it here.  It might help others that will be searching later.